# iPhone programming: How much data can I store in my app's Documents Directory (root folder)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The reason I ask is my app lets users cache map tiles. Does anyone know the real cap on how much data I can let them store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store as much as you want until you run out flash. Having said that, your users probably won't like it if you start eating all of the space on the phone.

Also, make sure you put it in the Cache folder, as opposed to Documents. The Documents folder gets backed up when you sync to iTunes, the Cache folder is not. If you have a ton of data in the Documents folder it will massively slow down iTunes synching.

Comment: If it weren't for Stack Overflow, I'd have to pay you for consulting work Louis.  :)

Answer (score 0):

About a year ago the word was there is a 2Gb limit on app size, but you'll be hard pressed to find an "official" declaration of such, even on apple's site or [the discussion forums](http://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa) there

That being said 2Gb is pretty hearty for a mobile app, caching and all

Comment: The 2GB is a limit on the size of the app itself (as in what is downloaded from the app store), not the data it can write to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any quota for apps using the writable area, but it would be easy enough to check.